# How to initiate from xib UIViewController in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib, carbonkit

I have been developing framework, I have used tab menu using carbonKit cocoapods, Now i'm trying to navigate UIVIewController xib.

When UITabBarController loaded the carbonkit menu default tab menu will be called.

Here is the code used for load xib UIViewcontroller

```
 public func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
    print("called carbonkit")       
    print("carbon kit index 0 called")

    return (UINib(nibName: "FirstViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: FirstViewController.self)).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? FirstViewController)!

}
```

Here is the console output:

```
 Called tab
   called carbonkit
  carbon kit index 0 called
 2019-11-12 22:13:02.350434+0530 A8FlowSampleApp[41059:1971714] *** 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
 reason: '[<NSObject 0x600000b1c8b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
 *** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4ebf9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff256f2ef3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 325
4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff474b9a52 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c3b052 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 242
6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff474b6bfa -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2190
7   A8Flow                              0x0000000104db51d8 $s6A8Flow6MyTaskC24carbonTabSwipeNavigation_16viewControllerAtSo06UIViewJ0CSo06CarbonfgH0C_SutF + 1016
8   A8Flow                              0x0000000104db546d $s6A8Flow6MyTaskC24carbonTabSwipeNavigation_16viewControllerAtSo06UIViewJ0CSo06CarbonfgH0C_SutFTo + 77
9   CarbonKit                           0x00000001048c1d31 -[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation viewControllerAtIndex:] + 593
10  CarbonKit                           0x00000001048c18fb -[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation loadFirstViewController] + 411
11  CarbonKit                           0x00000001048bc90e -[CarbonTabSwipeNavigation initWithItems:delegate:] + 350
12  A8Flow                              0x0000000104db69f2 $sSo24CarbonTabSwipeNavigationC5items8delegateABSayypGSg_yptcfcTO + 242
13  A8Flow                              0x0000000104db4bc2 $sSo24CarbonTabSwipeNavigationC5items8delegateABSayypGSg_yptcfC + 50
14  A8Flow                              0x0000000104db40ba $s6A8Flow6MyTaskC11viewDidLoadyyF + 378
15  A8Flow                              0x0000000104db4dcb $s6A8Flow6MyTaskC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 43
16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471cdb45 -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 83
17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471d2a9e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1084
18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47136b8c -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 160
19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47136e8c -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140
20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47137d56 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 868
21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471390c1 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47119ef7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47d34cfd -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2478
24  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b138d41 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 255
25  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b13ef33 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 517
26  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b14a86a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 80
27  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b0917c8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEd + 324
28  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff2b0c6ad1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 643
29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47867481 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb204c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bb17b8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bac644 
__CFRunLoopRun + 1284
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23babe16 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
34  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38438bb0 
GSEventRunModal + 65
35  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4784fb68 
UIApplicationMain + 1621
36  A8FlowSampleApp                     0x000000010458a6bb main + 75
37  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff51a1dc25 start + 1
38  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
  )
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
 NSException
 (lldb)
```

Any help much appreciated pls.. tried lot ways to achieve it but could not make it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself

```
func firstView() -> UIViewController {

    let cont = FirstViewController()
    self.tabContView?.addChild(cont)
    self.tabContView?.view.addSubview(cont.view)
    cont.didMove(toParent: tabContView)
    return cont
 }

public func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
print("called carbonkit")       
print("carbon kit index 0 called")

return firstView()

}
```